# Traduko por antipop

Tags: translation

Kiel vi dirus "antipop"? Kaj en la angla kaj en la hispana oni uzas tiun vorton, do, antipopa estus nova radiko, sed "anti" ne estas esperanta prefikso. Do, ĉu pli bone kontraŭpoa?
Ĉu filtro aŭ filtrilo?

Ĉu kontraŭpopilo?

Dankon

Comment: Ligilo kiel referenco: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pop_filter

Answer (score 4):

Mi uzas la vorton *blovoŝirmilo*.

Comment: Blovoŝirmilo pensigas min pri ĉi tio

Comment: Pri ĉi tio. http://www.studiomusic.cl/rode-dead-cat-protector-de-viento-para-microfonos-ntg-1-ntg-2.html